Polar codes and Reed-Muller codes
Can someone explain the construction, or give a definition, of polar codes, say for the binary symmetric channel?  [I seriously can't even find a definition.] I'd like an explanation, if possible, of the form:
A generator matrix is constructed by taking the rows of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)^{\otimes n}
$$
with property <blah>.
I'm led to believe by a blurb at the end of section 1.1 of A proof that Reed-Muller codes achieve Shannon capacity on symmetric channels that RM codes correspond to taking largest Hamming weights and polar codes to some probabilistic selection criterion.
Any readable reference to encoding polar codes would be fine by me (generator matrix, explicit description of codewords, an encoding algorithm, whatever).  Info on decoding would be nice too, but understanding "what is the code?" is my goal with this question.

perhaps related in Space SE: How is stacking oranges in 24 dimensions related to receiving and decoding signals from the Voyagers?

Disclaimer: I am not a deep expert in this topic.
The Polar Code depends on the channel more specifically the channel noise model. Briefly, it comes from the probabilistic approach to error correction coding [maximize channel capacity] (as opposed to the classical algebraic approach [maximize minimum distance]).
From a tutorial by Erdal Arikan, the inventor of Polar Codes:
Let $W:X\rightarrow Y$  denote a generic binary-input discrete memoryless channel
(B-DMC) with input alphabet $X$ , output alphabet $Y$ , and transition probabilities
$$W(y|x), x ∈ X , y ∈ Y.$$
There is a Polar Code associated with a specific B-DMC which achieves channel capacity efficiently (with relatively small blocklengths and low complexity encoding and decoding). The work proceeded over many years and was generalized in many different directions, originally for the BEC (Binary Erasure Channel).
From page 14:
Polar codes are channel-specific designs: a polar code for one channel may not be a polar code for another. The main result of this paper will be to show that polar coding achieves the symmetric capacity $I(W)$ of any given B-DMC $W.$
Intuitively, a code is a polar code if it chooses all the subchannels which have a higher individual capacity (or lower signal to noise ratio in terms of the Bhattacharya Parameter) compared to all the other subchannels.
You're right, RM codes choose the highest weight (lowest degree) rows but Polar codes use low noise rows. Amazingly, the Kronecker product of a $2\times2$ matrix is part of the specification of the 1st Order RM (i.e., Hadamard) code and the Polar Code.
The ISIT 2019 Shannon Lecture by Arikan is available here (I'm not sure if the link on IEEE is paywalled, it may be).
